# Import CERT in Google Chrome fails in Windows

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, certificate

I can import a certificate in Google Chrome (`Version 68.0.3440.106 (Official Build) (64-bit)`), in Linux (Mint Tara, Ubuntu based), but doing the same in Google Chrome `Version 68.0.3440.106 (Offizieller Build) (64-Bit)` in Windows 10 fails with:

> Dass Eingegebene Password ist falsch

("The given password is wrong")

It seems Google Chrome is using a Windows Backend to manage certificates.

What options do I have?

Comment: Chrome is using the underlying OS certificate store and as far as I know it's not possible to change this behaviour in Windows. However I cannot see how is this related to the error message which states you mistyped the certificate password.

Comment: @bcs78, but I did not mistyped it. I copy/pasted it. And I verified it works by copy/pasting in linux too.

Comment: I do believe you but that's what it says. This is all the info we have so most likely no one will be able to help you with this.

Comment: @bcs78 I have just verified this with multiple certs, which can be imported in Chrome in Linux. No luck with Chrome in Windows. I understand that there is little others can do to help, but for me it would be interesting to know if people can import the same password protected certificate in Windows **and** in Linux. The certificate was saved from Chrome in a Linux machine, as far as I can recall.

Comment: Interestingly, Firefox in Windows seems to use its own Certificate backend, and importing my certificates there work

Comment: That's correct, Firefox has its own cert store in Windows. This can complicate things a bit if you are in an Active Directory based enterprise environment and want to use a root certificate from a company CA in Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

This is a workaround:

1. Convert your password-protected certificate to a non-password-protected certificate
2. Move it to your Windows machine
3. Import it in `Chrome for Windows`. You will not be asked about a password
4. Delete the non-password protected certificate from the file system.

To unprotect a certificate, do as explained [here](https://serverfault.com/a/806384/91978):

```
» openssl pkcs12 -in cert-protected.p12 -nodes | openssl pkcs12 -export -out cert-no-pass.p12
Enter Import Password:
Enter Export Password:
Verifying - Enter Export Password:
```

As `Import Password` enter the original password, as `Export Password` enter an empty password.